# How do I replace text inside a FOR command?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

Inspired while writing my other question (which i now deleted) (sometimes [talking to the duck](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html) does help) I think I found a solution to my problem but I don't know how to do it.

I have the following command in a batch script

```
FOR /R %1 %%G IN (*) DO rdiff.exe signature "%%G" | 7za.exe a -mx0 -si"%%G" signatures.7z
```

What I would like to do is remove the text of `%1` from `%%G` in the 7zip `-si` argument but leave it in the rdiff argument.

How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String manipulation is very awkward in the command prompt. Removing the contents of `%1` from the beginning of `%G` would involve counting the characters of `%1` (loop through the characters and increase a counter by one) and then use the substring syntax (`%var:~start,length%`).

Using [forfiles](http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html) should be much simpler, since it has a built-in command variable to access the relative path of the file (`@relpath`).

This should work:

```
forfiles /S /P %1 /C "cmd /V:on /C if @isdir==FALSE set R=@relpath&set R=!R:~3,-1!&%~dp0rdiff signature @path | %~dp07za a -mx0 -si\"!R!\" %~dp0signatures.7z"
```

Details:

- `/S` makes forfiles recursive.
- `/P %1` specifies the path.
- `/C "cmd /V:on /C ...` executes `...` in a subshell with delayed variable expansion (`!var!` syntax).
- `if @isdir==FALSE` checks for the presence of a file (rather than a directory).
- `set R=@relpath` stores the relative path in a variable called `R`.
- `set R=!R:~3,-1!` removes the string at the beginning `"\."` and the trailing double-quote.
- `%~dp0` forfiles changes directories to execute the command, specifying `%~dp0` gives you the absolute path the batch file was run from.

Comment: That looks good, but its no longer seeing rdiff.exe in the same folder as the batch file. if I do `E:\rdiff>makeSig.bat E:\example` it gives me the error message `'rdiff.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Forfiles seems to change directories to execute the command. That means the executables, the signatures file and the archive will require full paths.

Comment: By the way, all the variable juggling doesn't seem to be necessary. Just using `-si\@relpath` should work as well.

Comment: replacing the file-names of the programs to `%~dp0rdiff.exe` and `%~dp07za` solved it. I also needed to add to the name of the zip to make `%~dp0signatures.7z`

Comment: Also if I just use -si\@relpath I get blank directory and a directory named `.` in the zip file. but the string replacement works great.

Comment: Ugly typo. Sorry. It should be `-si@relpath` (without backslash).